# Replace substring in python with matched after modify

Tags: python, regex, tags

I'm trying in python to replace substring in python with matched after modify it.
i have #ma{Z} and expect to replace it by #maZ.

```
line= '#ma{Z}'    
re.sub(t=r'\#\{\w\}',t - 1 , line)
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide an [mcve]. This won't even compile.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need Regex for this, `str.replace` to replace `{` and `}` with null string would do:

```
In [855]: str_ = '#ma{Z}'

In [856]: str_.replace('{', '').replace('}', '')
Out[856]: '#maZ'
```

If you insist on using Regex, use a character class for `{` and `}`, and again replace with null string:

```
In [857]: re.sub(r'[{}]', '', str_)
Out[857]: '#maZ'
```

---

**Edit based on comment:**

As you actually want to remove the braces around `Q` in `{<math>\\mathbb{Q}}`, you can use `\w+` to match one or more of alphanumerics or underscore and put the match in a captured group to refer it in the replacement with `re.sub`:

```
In [858]: str_ = '{<math>\\mathbb{Q}}'

In [859]: re.sub(r'\{(\w+)\}', r'\1', str_)
Out[859]: '{<math>\\mathbbQ}'
```

Comment: It does partially. I have {<math>\\mathbb{Q}} and after re.sub(r'[{}]', '', str_) i got <math>\\mathbbQ. But i need  {<math>\\mathbbQ}. Thank you.

Comment: Only braces around Q need to be deleted. Have no idea how to do it

Comment: @user3193813 You should use that very example in your question at the first place as thats a whole different thing; check my edits.

Comment: {<math>\\mathbb\x01} - What i need to do with "x01". I have a large text and it has  Q,Z,E and other patterns. There is an option to stay with character instead of  "x01"? Thank you, again

Comment: @user3193813 You need to treat the replacement as raw string to prevent Python interpretation beforehand, which is making the replacement `\x01`. Check my edits.

Answer (score 0):

If you have patterns like Q,Z,E it might be an option to use a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[EQZ]` or a specify a range to capture those in a group between curly braces `{}` and the replace with the capturing group:

[`{([EQZ])}`](https://regex101.com/r/ZbufJt/1)

```
import re
line = "#ma{Z}"
result = re.sub(r"{([EQZ])}", r"\1", line)

if result:
    print (result)
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/UDX85800)